# Query to remove all redundant entries from a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table that describes relationships between entities, this table is populated by a process which I cannot modify. This is an example of that table:

```
+-----+-----+
| e1  | e2  |
|-----+-----|
|  A  |  B  |
|  C  |  D  |
|  D  |  C  |
| ... | ... |
+-----+-----+
```

I want to write a SQL query that will remove all unecessary relationships from the table, for example the relationship `[D, C]` is redundant as it's already defined by `[C, D]`.

I have a query that deletes using a self join but this removes everything to do with the relationship, e.g.:

```
DELETE FROM foo USING foo b WHERE foo.e2 = b.e1 AND foo.e1 = b.e2;
```

Results in:

```
+-----+-----+
| e1  | e2  |
|-----+-----|
|  A  |  B  |
| ... | ... |
+-----+-----+
```

However, I need a query that will leave me with one of the relationships, it doesn't matter which relationship remains, either `[C, D]` or `[D, C]` but not both.

I feel like there is a simple solution here but it's escaping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A general solution is to use the always unique pseudo-column `ctid`:

```
DELETE FROM foo USING foo b WHERE foo.e2 = b.e1 AND foo.e1 = b.e2
    AND foo.ctid > b.ctid;
```

Incidentally it keeps the tuple whose physical location is nearest to the first data page of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that an exact duplicate row is constrained against, there will always be at most two rows for a given relationship: (C,D) and (D,C) in your example. The same constraint also means the two columns have a distinct values: the pair (C,C) might be legal, but cannot be duplicated.

Assuming that the datatype involved has a sane definition of `>`, you can add a condition that the row to be deleted is the one where the first column `>` the second column, and leave the other untouched.

In your sample query, this would mean adding `AND foo.e1 > foo.e2`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this in the question but the type involved is not comparable in any sensible way. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Jonathan Oh, well, at least I spotted that that was a pre-requisite of the approach. :)